# Enter data in a view using the dynamic model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

In view I want display data from list ucz and insert data to listaOcen. display the list of ucz works but I have no idea to input data into list listaOcen

```
@using biblioteka;
@model dynamic

    <tr>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.dl;i++ )
{

   td>@Model.Uczniowie[i]</td>
<td>
@Html.DropDownList(Model.listaOcen[i], new[] { //doesnt work
       new SelectListItem() { Text = "5", Value = "5" },
       new SelectListItem() { Text = "4+", Value = "4.75" },

}, "Select option")
<td>
</tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Add(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var dataContext = db.Uczniowie;
            var ucz = dataContext.Where(m => m.KlasaId == id)
                                 .Select(m => m.Nazwisko + " " + m.Imie);


            List<double> listOfOcena = new List<double>();
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            mymodel.Uczniowie = ucz.ToList();
            mymodel.dl = ucz.ToList().Count;
            mymodel.listaOcen = listOfOcena;// enter the data from DropDownLists
            return View(mymodel);
```

It is model.

```
public  class Ocena
    {         
        public string IdUcznia { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Przedmiot { get; set; }           
        public double Wartosc { get; set; }
        public double waga { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Data { get; set; }
        public string Rodzaj { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }

    }
```

Please help :)

Comment: can you show us your model?

Comment: Don't use `@model dynamic` If you need 2 models create a view model containing properties for this 2 models, or use `@Html.Action()` to call methods that return partial views for each of the models.

Comment: No. I need create one model, but I need data form list which create in controller (ucz - list).  In controller set I add record to database 
http://wklej.org/id/1761690/

Comment: @robert, Your code for the `DropDownList` does not make sense. Are you trying to create one dropdown list for each item in the collection (so that you can assign a value of `5` or `4.75` to it? - in which case it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.listaOcen[i], yourSelectList)`

Comment: And as I noted above, it needs to be `@model Ocena` (not `dynamic`)

Comment: I have 3 lists in the controller: 1st "ucz" only displays the name, 2 contains the "id" in the same order as the list of "learn" that the first item "learn" matches the corresponding id in the table in SQL. I want every element of the list (ucz) to assign a new list of values (selected idems) and then enter the number of records to the database if the elements in the list of "ucz". Other data such as the "Opis", "Rodzaj", "Waga" I read the textbox and save to model Ocena for each elements of list.

Comment: @robert, if you want to set multiple marks at once, you need to change `StudentMarkAssignViewModel` and make `Marks` be a `List<double>`. Then in cshtml page use the same technique to render multiple dropdowns per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert, first of all try to avoid dynamic model. Create a viemodel for your action. e.g.

```
    public class StudentMarkAssignViewModel
    {
        public long StudentId { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public double Mark { get; set; }
    }
```

then fill it in your action

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add(string id)
    {
        var model = new StudentMarkAssignViewModel[]
        {
            new StudentMarkAssignViewModel {StudentId = 1, FullName = "Martin", Mark = 0 },
            new StudentMarkAssignViewModel {StudentId = 2, FullName = "Robert", Mark = 5 }
        };
        //here i use hardcoded valuse, but you should get them from your db
        return View(model);
    }
```

after that you can render list of your students and assign them marks and submit it to the server

```
@using WebApplication100.Models

@model StudentMarkAssignViewModel[]

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "StudentMarks", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        @for (var index = 0; index < Model.Length; index++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[index].StudentId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[index].FullName)
                <td>@Model[index].FullName</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model[index].Mark, new SelectListItem[]{
                        new SelectListItem{ Value = "0", Text = "Not Rated", Selected = Model[index].Mark == 0  } ,
                        new SelectListItem{ Value = "5", Text = "5"  , Selected = Model[index].Mark == 5  } ,
                        new SelectListItem{ Value = "4.75", Text = "4+"  , Selected = Model[index].Mark == 4.75  }
               })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

after you submit the form, you'll get list of students and their marks on the server

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(StudentMarkAssignViewModel[] marksModel)
    {
        /* do whatever you need with your model*/
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

that's all. I hope you'll get the point.

Comment: @robert, why on earth do you try to post to Index action `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Klasas", FormMethod.Post)` and not Add action? after that it will not work again, because you do not have and `Id` rendered on your form. and you again misunderstand the way you should construct your viewmodels: why you use properties `Wartosc`, `Opis` etc. for every record? You should create viewmodel with this properties declared once and a list of `Wartosc`